# Installing pyGeo library on Colab

Tags: github, installation, import, google-colaboratory, networkx

I would like to import pyGeo in Colab. And test it by running an example code.

I have tried the straightforward way.

```
!git clone https://github.com/mdolab/pyspline.git 
!git clone https://github.com/mdolab/pygeo.git
!pip install ./pyspline
!pip install ./pygeo
```

And now on running,

`python ./pygeo/examples/ffd_cylinder/runFFDExample.py`

I get ImportError: cannot import name 'libspline' from partially initialized module 'pyspline' (most likely due to a circular import) (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pyspline/**init**.py)

How do you properly install pyGeo in Colab?